# What is the "correct" method to use pandas .loc accessor to select rows & columns from a DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

This question is heavily related to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682613/how-to-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-subset-of-columns-and-rows-into-a-numpy-array) that I asked, but I felt that these are two separate issues.

Here are two separate lines of codes. I think they should yield the same results but don't understand why the first one throws an exception. I suspect the first way is "incorrect" somehow, but don't know why...

```
df.loc[df.year.notnull(),['year']]   # LINE 1: throws "MemoryError" (see below)
df.loc[df.year.notnull()].year       # LINE 2: WORKS FINE
```

A little more info on the thrown exception:

```
../lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.pyc in get_indexer_non_unique(self, target, **kwargs)
    843             tgt_values = target.values
    844 
--> 845         indexer, missing = self._engine.get_indexer_non_unique(tgt_values)
    846         return Index(indexer), missing
    847
```

Sorry I haven't figured out how to reproduce the error with a toy example. My DataFrame "df" has 100,000 rows and 17 columns. It was sampled from a larger dataframe (1,000,000 rows and 89 columns). The larger dataframe was created using read_csv and index_col=False. I'm not sure if this information is relevant.

Comment: Both should work, thought the former will return a DataFrame rather than a Series. Please consider posting a github [issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)...

Comment: opened [issue 4280](http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4280)

Comment: Looks like the linked issue was fixed in 0.12