# Convert Pandas dtype of dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, k-means

I have a **Pandas** dataframe which is stored as an 'object', but I need to change the dataframe structure to an 'int' as the 'object' dtype will not process in the **kmeans()** function of **numpy** library

I have managed to convert each column of the dataframe into an float64,based on this example [Pandas: change data type of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/pandas-change-data-type-of-columns) but I can't change the whole thing into anything else.

```
 #create subset of user variables
 user.posts = user.posts.astype('int')
 user.views = user.views.astype('int')
 user.kudos = user.kudos.astype('int')

 Y = user[['posts','views','kudos']]
 #convert dataframe into float
 X.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dtypes

Out[205]:
 posts    float64
 views    float64
 kudos    float64
 dtype: object
```

This then causes issues when I try and run

```
K = range(1,10)

# scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans
KM = [kmeans(X,k) for k in K] # apply kmeans 1 to 10
```

I get the error

```
  --->KM = [kmeans(X,k) for k in K] # apply kmeans 1 to 10
  ^

  AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

What is the issue kmeans is having with either the K or X dataframe, and how can it be resolved?
Thanks

Comment: Answered! 
user.posts = user.posts.astype('float')
user.views = user.views.astype('float')
user.kudos = user.kudos.astype('float')

Y = user[['posts','views','kudos']].values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

save it just as the values, not the objects. per this post
[How to convert a pandas DataFrame subset of columns AND rows into a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682613/how-to-convert-a-pandas-dataframe-subset-of-columns-and-rows-into-a-numpy-array)

```
user.posts = user.posts.astype('float')
user.views = user.views.astype('float')
user.kudos = user.kudos.astype('float')

Y = user[['posts','views','kudos']].values
```